# using "rstrip" while appending itens to a json

Tags: python, append, strip

I'm trying to append URLs to a list that will be converted into a json later.

Those URLs have the same domain, and I know that they will only change after the version is exposed in such URL, for example:

"https://www.example.com/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem"

So, all I need is this portion of the URL in my json: "v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem"

My code currently is like this:

```
participants=[]

for institution in data[0:1]:
    for auth in institution["auth"]:
        for api in auth["api"]:
            myList.append({
                'ID':[institution["ID"]],
                'Name':[institution["Name"]],
                'ParentInstitution':[institution["ParentInstitution"]],
                'ParentId':[institution["ParentId"]],
                'Roles':[A["Role"] for A in institution["InstitutionRoles"]],
                'BrandId':[auth["BrandId"]],
                'ApiFamily':[api["ApiFamily"]],
                'ApiEndpoints':[A["ApiEndpoint"] for A in api["ApiEndpoints"]]
```

I'm later converting this data extraction in a json and using for other purposes.

Now it would be very helpful if my URLs are smaller, hence my need to strip it.

I believe I could do it like this:

```
'ApiEndpoints':[A["ApiEndpoint"].rstrip('/v1') for A in api["ApiEndpoints"]]
```

But this has no practical results on the URLs.

I understand that for it to work I would have to use something like this:

```
Stripped = ApiEndpoint.rstrip('/v1') (...)
```

but since I'm new to python I'm not quite sure how to do it inside the list I'm appending.

Could you give me a help?

Comment: It looks like you expect the part of the URL you want to keep to always start with `v1/`?

Comment: `rstrip` does something completely unrelated to what you're trying to do. (You should check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) for a method to understand what it actually does.)

Comment: first use `print()` to see what you get with `rstrip()`. It removes `v`, `1` `/` but only if they are on right end of string. You may need rather `split()` instead of strip()` - ie. `'v1/' + split('v1/')[-1] ` or `split('/', 3)[-1]` - or you could use `urllib.parser`

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. Yesterday I was rush testing every method with a name likely to work. Today on the first try with the split() method recomended by furas, the result was exactly what I expected.

I used: .split('/v1')[1]
Thank you for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could use `print()` to see what you get with `rstrip()`

`rstrip('v1/')` tries to remove every char `v`, `1`, `/` at the right end of the string - and they can be in any order.

`'something/v1/'.rstrip('v1/')` gives `'something'`

`'something/1111/vvvv/'.rstrip('v1/')` gives `'something'`

but

`'something/v1/other'.rstrip('v1/')` gives the same `'something/v1/other'`

---

Maybe you mean `split` instead `strip`.

`'something/v1/other'.split('v1/')` gives list `['something/', 'other']`

and you can use `[-1]` ot get last element and add again `'v1/'`

`'v1/' + 'something/v1/other'.split('v1/')[-1]` gives `'v1/other'`

But maybe it could be more useful with `/` and second argument - how many split to do

```
url = "https://www.example.com/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem"

url.split('/')
```

gives list

```
['https:', '', 'www.example.com', 'v1', 'item', 'anotheritem', 'otheritem']
```

but `url.split('/', 3)` gives

```
['https:', '', 'www.example.com', 'v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem']
```

And you can get `[-1]`

```
url = "https://www.example.com/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem"

url.split('/', 3)[-1]
```

gives

```
'v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem'
```

---

Or maybe you should use `urllib.parser.urlsplit` for this

```
url = "https://www.example.com/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem"

import urllib.parse

urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
```

gives

```
SplitResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.example.com', path='/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem', query='', fragment='')
```

and you can get `.path`

```
urllib.parse.urlsplit(url).path
```

gives

```
'/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem'
```

Comment: Hi furas. Thanks for the tips! I used one of your approachs and made it work.
I ended up inserting a <br> at the end to break the line in my html table, and to remove the comma separator of the list i used the js portion of my code with a .join in the end of the table dinamic build.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If my answer helped then you could mark it as accepted. And if you would have bigger reputation (bigger score) then you could upvote it after few minutes.

Comment: my reputation don't allow upvotes, but I accepted it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If all the urls have a path beyond the domain that starts with `v1/`, one approach would be:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/v1/item/anotheritem/otheritem'
part = url[url.index('v1/'):]
```

Using it in your code:

```
for institution in data[0:1]:
    for auth in institution["auth"]:
        for api in auth["api"]:
            myList.append({
                'ID': [institution["ID"]],
                'Name': [institution["Name"]],
                'ParentInstitution': [institution["ParentInstitution"]],
                'ParentId': [institution["ParentId"]],
                'Roles': [A["Role"] for A in institution["InstitutionRoles"]],
                'BrandId': [auth["BrandId"]],
                'ApiFamily': [api["ApiFamily"]],
                'ApiEndpoints': [A["ApiEndpoint"][A["ApiEndpoint"].index('v1/'):] for A in api["ApiEndpoints"]]
            })
```

Comment: Hi Grismar. It works like a charm in your example, but when applying to my code, on the .append section, I get an error, like python isn't recognizing index as a method:

'ApiEndpoints':[A["ApiEndpoint"][index('v1/', A["ApiEndpoint"]):] for A in Api["ApiEndpoints"]]
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That's likely because of a typo on my part - I didn't test for lack of test data in your example, but I updated.

Comment: I have made some tests of the time to process (I'm gathering some 2k lines from a json hosted at website).

Your approach:
PS C:\opb> python .\extracao.py
--- 0.6115820407867432 seconds ---
PS C:\opb> python .\extracao.py
--- 0.6161086559295654 seconds ---


split() approach:
PS C:\opb> python .\extracao.py
--- 0.5492348670959473 seconds ---
PS C:\opb> python .\extracao.py
--- 0.564584493637085 seconds ---

Since the later is slighty better, I've gone with it. But after your correction, your way works just aswell! Thanks!